# Scala Play 2.1: Accessing request and response bodies in a filter

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm writing a filter to log all requests and their responses

```
    object LoggingFilter extends EssentialFilter {
  def apply(next: EssentialAction) = new EssentialAction {
    def apply(rh: RequestHeader) = {
      val start = System.currentTimeMillis

      def logTime(result: PlainResult): Result = result match {
        case simple @ SimpleResult(header, content) =>
            val time = System.currentTimeMillis - start
            play.Logger.info(s"${rh.method} ${rh.uri} took ${time}ms and returned ${header.status}")
            result
        case _ => result
      }
      next(rh).map {
        case plain: PlainResult => logTime(plain)
        case async: AsyncResult => async.transform(logTime)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need to also log the request and response bodies. These are buried inside Iterators/Enumerators, is there an easier way to access the bodies without having to go into details of how iteratees work?
Otherwise how can I convert the request and response bodies as a string?

Comment: Did you figure it out? I can only get result body

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to capture the SimpleResult response body use this:

```
def logTime(result: PlainResult): Result = result match {
  case simple @ SimpleResult(header, content) => {
    val time = System.currentTimeMillis - start
    SimpleResult(header, content &> Enumeratee.map(a => {
      play.Logger.info(s"${rh.method} ${rh.uri} took ${time}ms and returned ${header.status} with body ${a}")
      simple.writeable.transform(a)
    }))
  }
  case _ => result
}
```

Check mimetype for json:

```
def logTime(result: PlainResult): Result = {
  result.header.headers.get(HeaderNames.CONTENT_TYPE) match {
    case Some(ct) if ct.trim.startsWith(MimeTypes.JSON) => result match {
      case simple @ SimpleResult(header, content) =>
        val time = System.currentTimeMillis - start
        SimpleResult(header, content &> Enumeratee.map(a => { 
          play.Logger.info(s"${rh.method} ${rh.uri} took ${time}ms and returned ${header.status} with body ${a}")
          simple.writeable.transform(a) 
        }))
    }
    case ct => result
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Assume it's a post request with json body, I would like to also log that body.

Comment: I updated it to include how to check for json only results. You could also use MimeTypes.HTML etc.

Comment: Thanks again. But I don't see where the request body is .. The modified code checks if the response header is json, I'm trying to log the _request_ body. This should be obtained from the iterator in the  `next` function I think.

Comment: The variable a is the body of the request. SimpleResult holds the header and body. The content &> Enumeratee applies the content Enumerator to a.

Comment: There must be a misunderstanding :) There is a request which has a header and body, ..etc and a response with another header and body. a is the _response_ body, I'm looking for the _request_ body as well. The `next` EssentialAction which is defined as `(RequestHeader => Iteratee[Array[Byte], Result]` takes the request header (`rh` in the code above) and consumes the `Array[byte]` which is the request body (which the only thing I'm missing here) to produce the result/response.

Comment: Ahh gotcha. I'd probably create a LoggingAction to capture the implicit request body, then follow it up with the EssentialAction filter in this case. http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ScalaActionsComposition

Comment: so do I have to compose the LoggingAction to every action in my application?

Comment: Yeah any action you would want to log. You can of course create any kinda of Action, then have a log mode or switch for it.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no easier way. But you can take a look on my [Google HTML Compressor](https://github.com/mohiva/play-html-compressor/blob/master/app/com/mohiva/play/htmlcompressor/HTMLCompressorFilter.scala) filter.

Comment: Thats for the result not request

Comment: One of the questions was how the response body can be converted as string. And this is what the HTML compressor do.